# 100% height in the wordpress container on the backend only with css

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Wordpress has this html structure in the backend...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ...>
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body class="wp-admin ...">
...
<div id="wpwrap">
    <div id="adminmenumain" role="navigation" aria-label="Main menu">
        ...
        <div id="adminmenuback"></div>
        <div id="adminmenuwrap">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="wpcontent">
        ...
        <div id="wpbody" role="main">
            <div id="wpbody-content">
                <div id="screen-meta" class="metabox-prefs">
                    ...
                </div>
                <div class="myplugin">
                    ...

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="wpfooter" role="contentinfo">
        <p id="footer-left" class="alignleft">
            ...
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

By the default #wpwrap has 100% of height and my problem is that I need #wpcontent, #wpbody and #wpbody-content with 100% height, because my plugin (.myplugin) has inside a sidebar and an area for content that I need both with 100% of height too...

I've tried several things... with table-cell #adminmenumain breaks and I don't want to touch things outside of #wpcontent... with position absolute... #wpfooter breaks if I have scroll in myplugin

Probably with a few lines of jquery I could resolve the problem, but I really want to do it only with CSS

Maybe someone with a wordpress installed, inspecting a little bit the code could give me some suggestion ... thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Use `min-height: 100vh;`,
all modern browsers support them, except Opera Mini browser.
https://caniuse.com/#search=vh

However you may always provide a fallback for browsers that do not support viewport-relative lengths using the old “`height: 100%`” option. 
But to get it working. Add this little bit:

```
html, body{
  height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ Mo'men ... I forgot to say I was playing with vh, but I'm a little worried about compatibility with browsers ... do you think that there could be another solution? Or at least a variant if the browser does not support it, thanks again